# Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings?

Tags: python, security, eval

If I am evaluating a Python string using eval(), and have a class like:

```
class Foo(object):
    a = 3
    def bar(self, x): return x + a
```

What are the security risks if I do not trust the string? In particular:

1. Is `eval(string, {"f": Foo()}, {})` unsafe? That is, can you reach os or sys or something unsafe from a Foo instance?
2. Is `eval(string, {}, {})` unsafe? That is, can I reach os or sys entirely from builtins like len and list?
3. Is there a way to make builtins not present at all in the eval context?

There are some unsafe strings like "[0] * 100000000" I don't care about, because at worst they slow/stop the program. I am primarily concerned about protecting user data external to the program.

Obviously, `eval(string)` without custom dictionaries is unsafe in most cases.

Comment: yes, if there's import sys sys.dostuff in the string you are doing eval on and you don't trust the strings stuff can get real ugly.

Comment: eval has the nice property it only allows expressions. So things like =, import, and print are not allowed.

Comment: Try `eval('__import__("sys").stdout.write("Hello Joe")')`

Comment: I advocate to replace `eval(strg)` with `ast.literal_eval(strg)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot secure eval with a blacklist approach like this.  See [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) for examples of input that will segfault the CPython interpreter, give access to any class you like, and so on.

Answer (score 59):

`eval()` will allow malicious data to compromise your entire system, kill your cat, eat your dog and make love to your wife.

There was recently a thread about how to do this kind of thing safely on the python-dev list, and the conclusions were:

- It's really hard to do this properly.
- It requires patches to the python interpreter to block many classes of attacks.
- Don't do it unless you really want to.

Start here to read about the challenge: http://tav.espians.com/a-challenge-to-break-python-security.html

What situation do you want to use eval() in? Are you wanting a user to be able to execute arbitrary expressions? Or are you wanting to transfer data in some way? Perhaps it's possible to lock down the input in some way.

Comment: @S. Lott — Isn't one of the driving ideas behind security to *prevent* bad things from happening rather than afterwards hoping you can both identify the attacker and convince them not to do it again? Why discourage good practices?

Comment: Any situation where a person on the greater internet to write untrusted code to run on your systems requires that the untrusted persons be unable to attack. "Who is this person" - if you wrote something insecure with eval() and I knew? It would be me to show you you shouldn't have done that.

Answer (score 14):

You can get to `os` using builtin functions: `__import__('os')`.

For python 2.6+, the [ast module](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast-helpers) may help; in particular `ast.literal_eval`, although it depends on exactly what you want to eval.

Comment: yes, I advocate to replace `eval(strg)` with `ast.literal_eval(strg)`

Answer (score 7):

Note that even if you pass empty dictionaries to eval(), it's still possible to segfault (C)Python with some syntax tricks. For example, try this on your interpreter: `eval("()"*8**5)`

Comment: Whoa, why did that cause a segfault?

Comment: It overflows the compiler's stack.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably better off turning the question around:

1. What sort of expressions are you wanting to eval?
2. Can you insure that only strings matching some narrowly defined syntax are eval()d?
3. Then consider if *that* is safe.

For example, if you are wanting to let the user enter an algebraic expression for evaluation, consider limiting them to one letter variable names, numbers, and a specific set of operators and functions.  Don't eval() strings containing anything else.

Comment: @S.Lott -- If he's writing cryptography programs it's either Carol or Eve, and for email handling its s.kiddie@aol.com but I don't know if we've ever identified who it is in the general case.

Comment: I'd go one step ahead and ask *why* you want to do this at all.

Comment: This is a good video entitled "28c3: The Science of Insecurity" describing interfaces between programs.

www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kEfedtQVOY

It strongly encourages input messages to be either regular or context free.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good [article on the un-safety of `eval()`](http://www.diveintopython3.net/advanced-iterators.html#eval) in Mark Pilgrim's [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython3.net/) tutorial.

Quoted from this article:

> In the end, it is possible to safely
>   evaluate untrusted Python expressions,
>   for some definition of “safe” that
>   turns out not to be terribly useful in
>   real life. It’s fine if you’re just
>   playing around, and it’s fine if you
>   only ever pass it trusted input. But
>   anything else is just asking for
>   trouble.

Comment: The link is no longer valid.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: Thanks, it appears that Mark has moved his domain. I've updated the links.