# How do you convert a stringed dictionary to a Python dictionary?

Tags: python

I have the following string which is a Python dictionary stringified:

```
some_string = '{123: False, 456: True, 789: False}'
```

How do I get the Python dictionary out of the above string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you can do

```
d = eval(some_string)
```

But if the string contains user input, it's a bad idea because some random malicious function could be in the expression.  See [Safety of Python 'eval' For List Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112665/safety-of-python-eval-for-list-deserialization)

So a safer alternative might be:

```
import ast
d = ast.literal_eval(some_string)
```

From http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval :

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following
>       Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
>       and None.

Answer (score 13):

Use [**`ast.literal_eval`**](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

Example:

```
>>> some_string = '{123: False, 456: True, 789: False}'
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(some_string)
{456: True, 123: False, 789: False}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only *safe* way to do it is with [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval) (it's safe because, differently from built-in `eval`, """The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.""".