# String of namedtuples to list

Tags: python, list, sqlite, type-conversion, namedtuple

How would I convert string of namedtuples to a list?

The problem is I have to store a list of namedtuples in a column in SQLite, which (obviously) doesn't support the format. I thought of just converting it into a string. However, since my tuple is a namedtuple, I don't know how to go from the string to list again.

```
>>> Point = namedtuple("Point", "x y", verbose = False)
>>> p = Point(3, 5)
>>> points = []
>>> points.append(Point(4, 7))
>>> points.append(Point(8, 9))
>>> points.append(p)
>>> p.x
3
>>> print points
[Point(x=4, y=7), Point(x=8, y=9), Point(x=3, y=5)]
```

My list of named tuples is something like this^^^^, but it has 6 arguments instead of the 2 shown above. Edit - the arguments are booleans, ints, and strings.

I tried mapping, but i got the following error:

```
>>> string = str(points)
>>> l = string.strip("[]")
>>> p = map(Point._make, l.split(", "))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
p = map(Point._make, l.split(", "))
File "<string>", line 17, in _make
TypeError: Expected 2 arguments, got 9
```

I'm open to other simpler ways to do this.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary why comment? it's perfect answer for this question

Comment: @RomanPekar feeling lazy, I though someone would add an answer. Anyway added the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, how to do this may be a matter of taste.

## JSON

Json can be a good use because, unlike pickle, it is usable beyond python. Your object is serialized in a widely supported, easily repurposed format.

```
>>> import json  # simple json is better bit I didn't want to force an install
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple("Point", "x y", verbose = False)
>>> p = Point(3,4)
>>> json.dumps(p._asdict())
'{"x": 3, "y": 4}'
>>> s = json.dumps(p._asdict())
>>> json.loads(s)  # not there yet cause thisis a dict
{u'y': 4, u'x': 3}   # but it is a dict that can create a Point
>>> Point(**json.loads(s))
Point(x=3, y=4)
```

## Pickle

pickle will not work unless you define a attribute state (see `__getstate__` [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)). 
This is "Nicer" in the load phase, following from above:

```
import pickle

# Point.__getstate__=lambda self: self._asdict() # not needed as per @simon's comment thx simon
>>> pickle.dumps(p)
"ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(c__main__\nPoint\np1\nc__builtin__\ntuple\np2\n(I3\nI4\ntp3\ntp4\nRp5\nccollections\nOrderedDict\np6\n((lp7\n(lp8\nS'x'\np9\naI3\naa(lp10\nS'y'\np11\naI4\naatp12\nRp13\nb."
s = pickle.dumps(p)
>>> pickle.loads(s)
Point(x=3, y=4)
```

## eval

I would discourage any use of eval or exec.  If you do go down that route check out [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) and checkout some of the SO related answers like [safety of python eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112665/safety-of-python-eval-for-list-deserialization)

Comment: Not sure why, but both in Python2.7.3 and Python3.3.2 pickle seems to support namedtuples out of the box.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to JSON, but i'm gonna go with pickle on this.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Phil Cooper answer, you can store your objects in json format:

```
>>> import json

>>> points_str = json.dumps([x._asdict() for x in points])
[{"x": 4, "y": 7}, {"x": 8, "y": 9}, {"x": 1, "y": 2}]

>>> points2 = [Point(**x) for x in json.loads(points_str)]
[Point(x=4, y=7), Point(x=8, y=9), Point(x=1, y=2)]
```

another strange way to do it is to use [exec](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec):

```
>>> points_str = repr(points)
'[Point(x=4, y=7), Point(x=8, y=9), Point(x=1, y=2)]'

>>> exec "points2 = %s" % points
>>> points2
[Point(x=4, y=7), Point(x=8, y=9), Point(x=1, y=2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to use modules like [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) that allow to to store python objects in files.

By the way I am not sure if `namedtuple` will work with `pickle`, if that's the case and  source of the data is not unknown then you can also use `eval` with `repr`:

help on `repr`:

```
>>> print repr.__doc__
repr(object) -> string

Return the canonical string representation of the object.
For most object types, eval(repr(object)) == object.
```

Example:

```
>>> repr(points)
'[Point(x=4, y=7), Point(x=8, y=9), Point(x=3, y=5)]'
>>> eval(repr(points))
[Point(x=4, y=7), Point(x=8, y=9), Point(x=3, y=5)]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. Will look into the pickle module once I have the time. I'd heard about it before but didn't pay attention to it. Anyways thanks.

Comment: In general you should really avoid to use `eval` as it will execute arbitrary code, no matter what it might do to your machine. `pickle.dumps(points)` and `pickle.loads(pickle_str)` is the safer and superior solution.