# What is python's 'restricted execution mode'?

Tags: python, security

When `__builtins__` is set and I try to access function globals, I get this error

```
>>> def f(): pass
... 
>>> f.func_globals
{'f': <function f at 0x00B83270>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>}
>>> __builtins__ = {}
>>> f.func_globals
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <string>
RuntimeError: restricted attribute
>>>
```

Why is that, where I can read more about it? Can I use it to safeguard expression evaluation?

See Question: [How safe is expression evaluation using eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994071/how-safe-is-expression-evaluation-using-eval)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, a long-obsolete concept, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/restricted.html?highlight=restricted) -- the original idea was to provide a safe / sandboxed mode, but it just didn't pan out and was abandoned and deprecated since 2.3.

Comment: Thanks, but it is still in action(python 2.5.1) as 'restricted attribute' shows

Comment: It's deprecated, abandoned, not supported, but fossil traces are left hanging around, of course:-(.