# regular expression Pattern object getting converted to string if fetched from config.cfg file

Tags: regex, python-2.7, configparser

python file

```
import ConfigParser,re

config=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
with open("temp.cfg",'r') as config_file:
    config.readfp(config_file)


x=[]
x.append(re.compile(r'abc'))
x.append((config.get("ssp",'a')).strip('"'))
print x[0]
print x[1]
```

config file[temp.cfg]

```
[ssp]
a:re.compile(r'abc')
```

output

```
>>> 
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x02110F80>
re.compile(r'abc')
>>>
```

What  "print x[1]" should give is regular expression object but it seems to be returning string.

Looks like I am not doing it in the right way & am unable to figure it out

Comment: What is inside `temp.cfg`?

Comment: that's config file. I have updated the question

Comment: I don't *speak* python but to me it seems you're trying to compile an empty regex `x.append(re.compile(r''))` and that's not allowed(?) so what you're seeing is the error output.

Comment: that's just an example ; my actual program have regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `x[1]` is because of the following:

```
x.append((config.get("ssp",'a')).strip('"'))
```

Since, `config` is the cfg file parser object, you are accessing the option `a` of `ssp` section:

```
[ssp]
a:re.compile(r'')
```

which is obviously, the **string**: ***`re.compile(r'')`***.

#### Using `eval`:

```
x.append(eval((config.get("ssp",'a')).strip('"')))
```

Comment: is there a way i can make my program understand that its a regular expression ?

Comment: eval seems to be working...let me give it a try..will get back to you...thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your config file to this:

```
[ssp]
a:abc
```

Then you can simply do (without ugly [`eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994071/how-safe-is-expression-evaluation-using-eval))

```
x.append(re.compile(config.get("ssp", "a")).strip())
```

You read the regex string **first** from config file and **then** translate it to a regex object in your code with `re.compile()` instead of `eval()`. That's also better for maintainance, because you save a lot of text in the config file (`a:abc` instead of `a:re.compile(r'abc')` for each line).

Comment: It's better not using `eval()` imho. Especially if you can avoid it. See [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) to get only an impression about using `eval()` Does my example work for you?

Comment: x.append(re.compile(config.get("ssp", "a")).strip()) give different address for e.g >>> 
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x02310F80>
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x0223AC50>

Comment: That's only the address in the memory where the pattern is saved. Normally, it isn't really interesting. I don't get the relevance for it. Do you need to proof if regexes reference to same object in memory or change regex outside of Python (the latter one is not a good idea at all, for the first one you need at least two same string regexes)?

Comment: More information: The output for the compiled regex (which you cannot have in a human-friendly way) is a `__repr__()`, i.e. a helpful information which have a little object information and the memory address (I'm not sure, but I think `id()` was taken internally). So this information is only relevant if you want to ensure/test object identity like _object A_ __is__ _object B_: _True_ / _False_.

Comment: it wasn't working & I have other things to do so i am using eval for the time being