# python string conversion for eval

Tags: python, regex, string, eval, expression

I have list like:

```
['name','country_id', 'price','rate','discount', 'qty']
```

and a string expression like

```
exp = 'qty * price - discount + 100'
```

I want to convert this expression into

```
exp = 'obj.qty * obj.price - obj.discount + 100'
```

as I wanna eval this expression like `eval(exp or False, dict(obj=my_obj))`

my question is what would be the best way to generate the expression for python eval evaluation....

Comment: user input, its being used in dynamic way, where user needs to change their expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you have to be **[very careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings/661128#661128)** using eval. Would be interesting to know why you need to use eval for this at all

This way makes it harder for something bad to happen if a malicious user finds a way to put non numeric data in the fields

```
import re
exp = 'qty * price - discount + 100'
exp = re.sub('(qty|price|discount)','%(\\1)f', exp)%vars(obj)
```

Comment: I can use literal eval also, but expression is dynamically entered by end user !

Comment: @shahjapan: Use `literal_eval` -- that's what it's there for!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the list you have is the list of available obj properties.

If it is so, I'd suggest to use regular expressions, like this:

```
import re

properties = ['name', 'country_id', 'price', 'rate', 'discount', 'qty']
prefix = 'obj'
exp = 'qty * price - discount + 100'

r = re.compile('(' + '|'.join(properties) + ')')
new_exp = r.sub(prefix + r'.\1', exp)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to loop through each of your potential variables, and replace all instances of them in the target string.

```
keys = ['name','country_id', 'price','rate','discount', 'qty']
exp = 'qty * price - discount + 100'

for key in keys:
    exp = exp.replace(key, '%s.%s' % ('your_object', key))
```

Output:

```
'your_object.qty * your_object.price - your_object.discount + 100'
```