# How to get the expression which has the maxium result in a string list?

Tags: python

For example, I have a list `a = ['3*4', '2*3', '4*6']`,

I want to print the string in the list whose result will be the largest, '4*6' in this case.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> a = ['3*4', '2*3', '4*6']
>>> max(a, key=eval)
'4*6'
```

with the [usual caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084) about using eval of course