# Python - Printing Hex from a file

Tags: python, file, printing, hex

I have the following code:

```
code1 = ("\xd9\xf6\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5f\x29\xc9\xbd\x69\xd1\xbb\x18\xb1")
print code1

code2 = open("code.txt", 'rb').read()
print code2
```

code1 output:

```
�צ�t$פ_)�½i�»±
```

code2 output:

```
"\xd9\xf6\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5f\x29\xc9\xbd\x69\xd1\xbb\x18\xb1"
```

I need code2 (which I read from a file) to have the same output as code1.
How can i solve this ?

Comment: What do you have in code.txt? a string like that: `"\xd9\xf6\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5f\x29\xc9\xbd\x69\xd1\xbb\x18\xb1"` or the bytes represented by this string?

Comment: I have "\xd9\xf6\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5f\x29\xc9\xbd\x69\xd1\xbb\x18\xb1" in my text file. when i put it in the a variable and print it its comes out as binary data which is what i need, but when i read it from a file and it prints it as a string

Comment: What is the output of `sys.getdefaultencoding()`?

Comment: @Shai - so your solution is in the answer below :)

Comment: ok, I just realised, that quotes are part of the output, so you just need to strip them off.

Answer (score 5):

To interpret a sequence of characters such as

```
In [125]: list(code2[:8])
Out[125]: ['\\', 'x', 'd', '9', '\\', 'x', 'f', '6']
```

as Python would a string with escaped characters, such as

```
In [132]: list('\xd9\xf6')
Out[132]: ['\xd9', '\xf6']
```

use `.decode('string_escape')`:

```
In [122]: code2.decode('string_escape')
Out[122]: '\xd9\xf6\xd9t$\xf4_)\xc9\xbdi\xd1\xbb\x18\xb1'
```

In Python3, the `string_escape` codec has been removed, so the equivalent becomes

```
import codecs
codecs.escape_decode(code2)[0]
```

Comment: string_escape... this is nice!

Answer (score 3):

This example:

```
import binascii

code1 = "\xd9\xf6\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5f\x29\xc9\xbd\x69\xd1\xbb\x18\xb1"
code2 = "\\xd9\\xf6\\xd9\\x74\\x24\\xf4\\x5f\\x29\\xc9\\xbd\\x69\\xd1\\xbb\\x18\\xb1"

print code1 == binascii.unhexlify(code2.replace('\\x', ''))
```

prints `True`.

You can use `binascii.unhexlify` to convert hexadecimal text representation to binary, but first have to remove `\x` from the string.

**EDIT**: I've just realised that double quotes are part of your output. Essentially you need to pass just valid hex string, so everything else need to be stripped off. In your case you need to pass `code2.replace('\\x', '').strip('"')` to `unhexlify`. You can use `eval` and probably will, but consider this [Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings) for future choices.

Answer (score -3):

`print eval(code2)` should do the job.

Comment: Beware of the `evil Eval`...   This trick is good enough for learning / debug purposes, but shouldn't be applied to production logic.

Comment: I thought as the shortest solution this one would be the most elegant, but the voice of the people objects.  Perhaps I should have prepended a regex match to assert that code.txt really contains a Python string literal.