# How to cast string back into a list

Tags: python, string, list, casting

I have a list:

```
ab = [1, 2, a, b, c]
```

I did:

```
strab = str(ab).
```

So `strab` is now a string.

I want to cast that string back into a list.

How can I do that?

Comment: @aaronman: No, that's wrong.

Comment: @aaronman: because that will make a list comprised of each character in the string.  It won't recover the original list.

Comment: @aaronman: Because `list(str([1, 2, 3]))` doesn't give `[1, 2, 3]`, it gives `['[', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '3', ']']`

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thats exactly what I intended it to do, I assumed it was a list of chars

Comment: @aaronman Even if it's a list of chars, you get additional `[`s, spaces and `,`s mixed in.

Comment: @aaronman `list(any_iterable)` gives you a list of the elements contained as they would come out in a `for` loop.

Comment: @aaronman and `for c in strab: print c` gives you every character in the string, which, as David Robinson has said, gives you the brackets, commas, and spaces.

Comment: @RyanHaining I don't speak python

Comment: @aaronman then don't answer python questions with such snide comments.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest and safest way would be to use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

ab = [1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c']    # a list
strab = str(ab)               # the string representation of a list
strab
=> "[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c']"

lst = ast.literal_eval(strab) # convert string representation back to list
lst
=> [1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c']

ab == lst                     # sanity check: are they equal?
=> True                       # of course they are!
```

Notice that calling [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) also works, but [it's not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings) and you should not use it:

```
eval(strab)
=> [1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the ast package:

```
import ast
lst = ast.literal_eval(strab)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the context of setting a numpy array element with a sequence, you can use the built-in join to bypass setting it to a string:

```
str_list_obj = '-'.join(list_obj)
```

and afterwards when needed split the string sequence again with the same connector (provided it does not appear in the list's strings):

`og_list_obj = str_list_obj.split("-")`