# Python String Parsing Floats

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to change a '14/15' string to a float?
I am trying to extract data from a text file would like to convert '1/3' to a float. float('1/3') doesn't work. I was thinking about splitting into two parts at '/' by 1 and 3 then dividing, but it seems cludgy. Is there a more pythonic way to do this? I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Do you only need to parse `X/Y`, or are you looking for a more general expression evaluator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trust your input:

```
from __future__ import division

eval('14/15')
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks, @nullstellensatz.

Comment: Also, really dangerous if you don't know where your data came from.

Answer (score 2):

If you only ever need to evaluate simple `X/Y` fractions:

```
s = "14/15"
num, denom = map(float, s.split("/", 1))
print(num / denom)
```

If you need a more complete expression evaluator, take a look at the [`asteval`](http://newville.github.io/asteval/) module.

Using `eval()` might also see like a nice easy way to do it, but I'd advise against it for [security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings).