# How to plot a math function from a string

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, evaluation, math-functions

I have a string, `"x * (x - 32 ( 2 /x) )"`, which represents a math function. How can I use `python` and `matplotlib` to convert this string into an array of points to plot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can turn a string into code by using pythons [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function, **but this is dangerous and generally considered bad style**.

- [Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/661128/3838691)
- [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/7758804)

If user can input the string, they could input something like
`import subprocess; subprocess.check_call(['rm', '-rf', '*'], shell=True)`.

So be sure that you build in reasonable security into this.

You can define a function that takes a string and returns a function.
We need to do a little preprocessing to allow the user to input formulas more like he is used to (^ etc.):

### Whitelist instead of blacklist

It seems better to define allowed and supported words than blacklisting some:

```
import re

replacements = {
    'sin' : 'np.sin',
    'cos' : 'np.cos',
    'exp': 'np.exp',
    'sqrt': 'np.sqrt',
    '^': '**',
}

allowed_words = [
    'x',
    'sin',
    'cos',
    'sqrt',
    'exp',
]

def string2func(string):
    ''' evaluates the string and returns a function of x '''
    # find all words and check if all are allowed:
    for word in re.findall('[a-zA-Z_]+', string):
        if word not in allowed_words:
            raise ValueError(
                '"{}" is forbidden to use in math expression'.format(word)
            )

    for old, new in replacements.items():
        string = string.replace(old, new)

    def func(x):
        return eval(string)

    return func


if __name__ == '__main__':

    func = string2func(input('enter function: f(x) = '))
    a = float(input('enter lower limit: '))
    b = float(input('enter upper limit: '))
    x = np.linspace(a, b, 250)

    plt.plot(x, func(x))
    plt.xlim(a, b)
    plt.show()
```

Result:

```
$ python test.py
enter function: f(x) = x^2
enter lower limit: 0
enter upper limit: 2
```

[image]

And for a malicious user:

```
enter function: f(x) = import subprocess; subprocess.check_call(['rm', '-rf', '*'], shell=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 35, in <module>
    func = string2func(input('enter function: f(x) = '))
  File "test.py", line 22, in string2func
    '"{}" is forbidden to use in math expression'.format(word)
ValueError: "import" is forbidden to use in math expression
```

### Blacklist hazardous words

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# there should be a better way using regex
replacements = {
    'sin' : 'np.sin',
    'cos' : 'np.cos',
    'exp': 'np.exp',
    '^': '**',
}

# think of more security hazards here
forbidden_words = [
    'import',
    'shutil',
    'sys',
    'subprocess',
]

def string2func(string):
    ''' evaluates the string and returns a function of x '''
    for word in forbidden_words:
        if word in string:
            raise ValueError(
                '"{}" is forbidden to use in math expression'.format(word)
            )

    for old, new in replacements.items():
        string = string.replace(old, new)

    def func(x):
        return eval(string)

    return func
```