# Math Eval String in DataFrame Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, eval

```
>>> df['X'].head()
0    25+4
1    25+5
2    15+3
3    20+2
4    20+3
Name: X, dtype: object
```

How do I evaluate this so my dataframe is this:

```
>>> df['X'].head()
0    29
1    30
2    18
3    22
4    23

Name: X, dtype: int64
```

Comment: A word of warning: `eval`ing arbitrary Python code is [potentially dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), especially if the code comes from an external source that you cannot 100% trust. Remember [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are security concerns, you can use `eval` to evaluate each element using a `lambda` expression.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['25+4', '25+5', '15+3', '20+2', '20+3']})

>>> df
      X
0  25+4
1  25+5
2  15+3
3  20+2
4  20+3

>>> df.X.apply(lambda x: eval(x))
0    29
1    30
2    18
3    22
4    23
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

For a description of security concerns, see:

- [Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings)
- https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html
- [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)