# This python code is not solving equations

Tags: python, bots, irc, instant-messaging, payload

I have a chat bot for an Instant messenger and I am trying to make a math solver for it but it can't send the solution of equation to the Instant messenger, it sends equation instead.

If someone from Instant messenger sends "solve: 2+2", this program should send them "4" not "2+2".

**Main problem:**

```
if (parser.getPayload().lower()[:6]=="solve:"):
                    parser.sendGroupMessage(parser.getTargetID(), str(parser.getPayload()[7:]))
```

**output:**

[it's sending same input again not the answer of equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf4ND.png)

**Test:**
I tested something and that's working properly. If I add this code, program will send solution of equation:

```
if (parser.getPayload().lower()=="test"):
                    parser.sendGroupMessage(parser.getTargetID(), str(2 + 2 -3 + 8 * 7))
```

**Output:**
[Working perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHg55.png)

Comment: Try using the `eval` statement in python. `eval("2+2")` will give you `4`.

Comment: @PrestonHager `eval` is *highly discouraged*. `ast.literal_eval` is better

Comment: Yep, ast module looks good. Try `ast.literal_eval("2+2")` instead. Don't forget to import ast, `import ast`.

Comment: um gentlemen, you are teaching him how to eval random code he gets from a chat?  @Bharat, please note that people will send you anything, i.e. instead of 2+2 they will save solve <followed by code to delete all your files>

Comment: It's solved. Thanks @PrestonHager, Andrew L. and MK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do this evaluating math expressions in string form.

However, user inputs are dangerous if you are just `eval` things whatever they give you. [Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings)

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to lower the risk.

Or you can use a evaluator from answers of following question
[Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Your test code

```
str(2 + 2 -3 + 8 * 7)
```

is distinct from your production code

```
str(parser.getPayload()[7:])
```

which gets expanded into

```
str("2 + 2 -3 + 8 * 7")
```

assuming you pass in the same equotation. Good thing is you have the plumbing working, now you need to implement the actual math solver like

```
str(solve_math(parser.getPayload()[7:]))

def solve_math(expr : str) -> float:
    """
    Parses and evaluates math expression `expr` and returns its result.
    """
```

Here you need to first parse the expression string into some structure representing the data, the operators / functions and the evaluation order. So your "2 + 2" expression gets turned into something like `Addition(Const(2), Const(2))` while expression "2 + 2 * 3" gets turned into somethng like `Addition(Const(2), Multiplication(Const(2), Const(3)))` and then you need to just evaluate it which should be fairly simple.

I recommend `pyparsing` to help you with that.

Comment: Thank you for explaining everything.