# python, how to assign object of a class already created with name in string variable

Tags: python, string, class, object

Below is my code requirement :

```
Class Employee:
    def __init__(self,age):
        self.age= age

main():

Mike = new Employee(20)
NamedEmployee = "Mike"

# Need some logic to refer Mike Object with value given in NamedEmployee 
string
# example
print(NamedEmployee.age) -- expect 20 here.
```

Need some insights in how to achieve this in python.

Comment: Better use a dict: `employees = {}; employees['Mike'] = new Employee(20)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Namedemployee to be uniquely defined by Mike then you can use

```
    Class Employee:
        def __init__(self,age):
            self.age= age

    Mike = Employee(20)
    NamedEmployee = eval("Mike")
    print(NamedEmployee.age) # print 20
```

if you want to have a category of, define a dict like :

```
    NamedEmployee = dict() 
    NamedEmployee['Mike'] = eval("Mike")
```

Note: becareful with eval() due to security issues , see [Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings)