# Input Statement Only Returning Str Type - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, input

[image]

Having trouble understanding why this is returning a str although I entered an int.  Could someone please explain this? When you enter a value in input does it only capture the value as a string?

Comment: All inputs are strings.  You have to convert it to another format if you want it as an int or float.

Answer (score 1):

In Python `3.x`, [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns the entered value as is (`str`) instead of evaluating it, so you should do `int(input('Please input number:'))` to get the value as an `int`.

In Python `2.x`, however, [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) would return the raw `str` value, while [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) would evaluate the entered value, as you can read on the docs:

> **input([prompt])**
>
> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.
>
> ...
>
> Consider using the `raw_input()` function for general input from users.

You can mimic this behavior in Python `3.x` with [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval): `eval(input('Please input number:'))` if you really need to, but first take a look at [Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings)

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense that is why I have been seeing it both ways.  Thank you!