# Bytes object stored in "repr format" as b'foo' instead of encode()-ing to string -- how to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

Some hapless coworker saved some data into a file like this:

```
s = b'The em dash: \xe2\x80\x94'
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(s))
```

when they should have used

```
s = b'The em dash: \xe2\x80\x94'
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s.decode())
```

Now `foo.txt` looks like

```
b'The em-dash: \xe2\x80\x94'
```

Instead of

```
The em dash: —
```

I already read this file as a string:

```
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    bad_foo = f.read()
```

Now how can I convert `bad_foo` from the incorrectly-saved format to the correctly-saved string?

Comment: `.decode` doesn't make sense without an encoding name. Why are you using byte strings in the first place, anyway? The idiomatic way to do this is to use a Unicode string and let Python encode it when writing to a file.

Comment: @tripleee someone else did it, and I've been tasked with undoing it :)

Comment: I suspect nothing much more useful than `eval` can be suggested for undoing this.

Comment: @tripleee this was intended as a self-answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53730411/2954547

Comment: Also in Py3 .decode() uses UTF-8 by default.

Comment: Does `eval(bad_foo).decode()` solves it? Can check it myself right now.

Comment: @shadowtalker there's a "answer your own question" checkbox just below the "Post Your Question" button on the Ask Question page that let's you get your answer in before the competition ;-)

Comment: @LuckyJosh `eval` is not safe against malicious input - see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661084/5320906).  `ast.literal_eval` is safer.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yeah, I know that `eval` is unsafe. I guess, I should have included a warning in my comment. But `ast.literal_eval` I did not know about, learned something new today. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If you trust that the input is not malicious***, you can use `ast.literal_eval` on the broken string.

```
import ast

# Create a sad broken string
s = "b'The em-dash: \xe2\x80\x94'"

# Parse and evaluate the string as raw Python source, creating a `bytes` object
s_bytes = ast.literal_eval(s)

# Now decode the `bytes` as normal
s_fixed = s_bytes.decode()
```

Otherwise you will have to manually parse and remove or replace the offending repr'ed escapes.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [literal eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
from ast import literal_eval
test = r"b'The em-dash: \xe2\x80\x94'"
print(test)
res = literal_eval(test)
print(res.decode())
```

Answer (score -2):

This code is working correct in my computer. But if you still get error, this may help you

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: No, the problemeis that the file contains the `repr()` of the byte string.