# Print a list from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing

```
Lists1 = [1,2,4,4]
Lists2 = [2,4,4]
Lists3 = [1,7]

List = input("input name of list to be printed: ")
```

How would I write the print command for this?
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I would make a dictionary, so you can just print the value of the required key.

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to create a [minimal,complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question with what you want to achieve and your try code

Comment: @Austin agreed dictionary is definitely the way to go with this

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways, either by making a dictionary which includes all lists that are available for printing or by using `eval` which is not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings).

```
lists = {
  'List1': [1,2,4,4],
  'List2': [2,4,4],
  'List3': [1,7]
}

text = input("input name of list to be printed: ")
print(lists[text])
```

Or

```
List1 = [1,2,4,4]
List2 = [2,4,4]
List3 = [1,7]

text = input("input name of list to be printed: ")
print(eval(text))
```

Output for both code segments:

```
input name of list to be printed: List1
[1, 2, 4, 4]
```

Comment: When you propose to use a dict, there is no need to use `eval`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I am not sure what the asker wants, so that's why I included both ways. Eval appears to be simple to some users, but is it a security risk

Comment: I'd argue it is more complex to use `eval` as dictionaries can also group the data contained in the lists together if they are related, as well as providing other useful methods and exceptions. However, `eval` does do the job.

Comment: @LeonisSupreme I agree for a larger code segment, `eval` would definitely hinder the developing or even testing process. I prefer the dict approach as well. I included `eval` as an example of what can be done, but maybe shouldn't be done. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This code prints each element of the specified list.

```py
Lists1 = [1,2,4,4]
Lists2 = [2,4,4]
Lists3 = [1,7]

List = input("input name of list to be printed: ")

if List == "Lists1":
    for i in Lists1:
        print(i)
elif List == "Lists2":
    for i in Lists2:
        print(i)
elif List == "Lists3":
    for i in Lists1:
        print(i)
else:
    print("List doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by inserting them in dict

```
list_dict = {"Lists1":[1,2,4,4],
"Lists2":[2,4,4],
"Lists3" :[1,7]
}
List = input("input name of list to be printed: ")
print(list_dict.get(List))
#[1,2,4,4]
```