# how to convert request.args from string to list?

Tags: python, flask

I have such url:

```
http://0.0.0.0:5000/test?id=00000&coords=[55.530974,37.522081]
```

And there is some part of the code:

```
id = request.args.get('id')
 >'00000'

coords = request.args.get('coords')
> '[55.530974,37.522081]'
```

I need to get coords not like a string, but like a list [55.530974,37.522081]

Is there solution to convert it? Or make in another way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(coords)` So `ast.literal_eval('[55.530974,37.522081]')` will return `[55.530974, 37.522081]`

Comment: Is `coords` always size 2?  Would it be easier to pass something like `x_coord` + `y_coord`?

Comment: Please never use an eval function with input from a url, it's a disaster waiting to happen

Comment: @Ram Using `eval` is extremely insecure, and using it in this context would open up a huge vulnerability

Comment: @Wondercricket I am not aware of that. Could you explain why is that?

Comment: @Ram There are many articles on that. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings) is one to start

Comment: @Wondercricket It really is INSECURE. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> [float(n) for n in coords[1:-1].split(",")]
[55.530974, 37.522081]
```

Slice from `[1:-1]` to ignore the `[]`

Answer (score 0):

The server receives the coords from a url, outside of the python runtime. Because of this, it will always come in as a string. The only was is to parse the string into an array of floats. You can either:

- Split the `coords` query parameter into two different ones, individually parse them as floats and then assemble them into an array
- Create a function that parses the array

I would recommend the first one; it is very common to send coordinates like this: `?long=1.11&lat=2.22`

Answer (score 0):

Do some string manipulations like `strip()` and `split()` and convert it into a `list`.

```
coords = '[55.530974, 37.522081]'

coords = coords.strip('[')
coords = coords.strip(']')
l = list(map(float, coords.split(',')))
print(l)
```

```
[55.530974, 37.522081]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the possibility to change how the http request is made, and you are sure that the passed coordinates are always separated by a comma and you have curly brackets at the ends, then you can convert the string to a list in the following way

```
coords = request.args.get("coords").strip()[1:-1].split(",")
```