# Calculate by user input

Tags: python, calculation

I want my program to do this:

1. Input formula:

   `(2*(3+4)-5)/6`
2. Output answer of formula:
   `1.5`

Is there anyway to do it? I can't find anything from the Internet. Asking here is my last attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use eval

```
>>> a = eval('(2*(3+4)-5)/6')
>>> print(a)
1.5
```

Comment: @cpm note that `eval` is a security risk, especially if you feed it user input.

Comment: Umm... What means "security risk"? Sorry but i dont understand

Comment: If someone feeds arbitrary code (to delete files, perform network actions, etc.), it will be executed. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings) for example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that security hole out. I have now patched my code so it exits if characters except numbers, +-*/ or . are found