# Concatenate string to dictionary path when using print in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I want to create a variable such as 'path' and use it to get the same result when getting data from the dictionary. Is this concatenation possible by doing some type of conversions?

```
print(dict['detect'][1]['ssh'][0]['Server']) #Result

path = "['ssh'][0]['Server']"
print(dict['detect'][1]{path}) #...should give same result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, you can use `eval()` to treat the string data as code:

```py
print(eval(f"dict['detect'][1]{path}")
```

That being said, be very careful when using `eval()`, as [it introduces major security risks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661084/17769815). I don't see a way to use `ast.literal_eval()` here, so if at all possible I would suggest avoiding this appoach entirely.