# List updation statement showing index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
 List=eval(input('enter list of numbers and string :'))
    for x in range(1,len(List)+1,2):
        List[x]=List[x]*2
    print(List)
```

*i want to update value at odd index but, why i don't know the statement 3 is generating error**List[x]=List[x]*2** showing me error -index out of range**

Comment: `list` indices are from 0 to `length - 1`. The loop should have `range(0,len(List)-1,2)`

Comment: no i dont watnt zero in my range, but fortunately not its working

Comment: You still have to stop at `len(List)`, not `len(List)+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three issues with your code:

1. `eval()` on user input is [risky business](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661084/17769815). Use `ast.literal_eval()` instead.
2. Your `for` loop has an off-by-one error. Remember that array indices start at zero in Python.
3. `List` is not a good variable name, as it conflicts with `List` from the `typing` module. Use something like `lst` instead.

```py
import ast
lst = ast.literal_eval(input('enter list of numbers and string :'))
for x in range(0, len(lst), 2):
    lst[x] = lst[x] * 2
print(lst)
```

Comment: I have to repeat what @BrokenBenchmark wrote, because it can't be said too often..  Under no circumstance should you **ever** use eval on user input.   The user can type anything--delete all the files in my home directory--and Python will happily do it.  `eval` should be used rarely, and only with input that you control.

Comment: can you please tell me the difference between using eval and ast.litreal_eval. Is there any advantage in using ast.literal_eval

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).