# Iterate through list of dictionaries in Python and return value

Tags: python, dictionary, eval, nested-loops, nested-lists

I have a list of dictionaries in this format:

```
user_input =[{
    'user':'guest',
    'record':
    '{"message":"User Request","context":{"session_id":"YWOZe"},"level":100}'
},
{
    'user':'guest',
    'record':
    '{"message":"User Inquiry","context":{"session_id":"YWOZf"},"level":100}'
},
]
```

What I want is, I want to use eval in eval(user_input[0]['record']) and eval(user_input[1]['record']) by iterating over two dictionaries, so far I could do for one dictionary as

```
def record_to_objects(data:dict):
    new_dict = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        if data[key] == data['record']:
            new_dict['record'] = eval(data['record'])
            r = data
            del r['record']
            return {**r, **new_dict}
```

But for two dictionaries in a list, I got only one result(as the last item) using "double for loop", maybe I am not returning in a proper way.
Expected output:

```
output = [
    
    {'user': 'guest',
     'record': {'message': 'User Request',
                'context': {'session_id': 'YWOZe'},
                'level': 100}},
    
    {'user': 'guest',
     'record': {'message': 'User Inquiry',
                'context': {'session_id': 'YWOZf'},
                'level': 100}}
]
```

**Can somebody help me?** I want a list of dictionaries and both should have been processed by the eval method.

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you can please edit the question to show what output you are hoping to get in this example. Most likely, a good solution will not involve the use of `eval`.

Comment: If i understand well you want to replace the string representing dict into the evaluated dict (object)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like JSON. [You should not use `eval()` for this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661084/17769815). Instead, use `json.loads()` with a `for` loop:

```py
import json

for item in user_input:
    item["record"] = json.loads(item["record"])
```

This outputs:

```py
[
 {
  'user': 'guest',
  'record': {'message': 'User Request', 'context': {'session_id': 'YWOZe'}, 'level': 100}
 },
 {
  'user': 'guest',
  'record': {'message': 'User Inquiry', 'context': {'session_id': 'YWOZf'}, 'level': 100}
 }
]
```

Comment: I want the remaining data as well not only item['record'], how can I get remaining data and merged with these outputs for each dictionaries.

Comment: See the edit to my post.

Comment: Thanks, nearly got the result, but still I want in a list of dictionaries, this gave me one whole dictionary.
`{'user': 'guest', 'record': {'message': 'User Request', 'context': {'session_id': 'YWOZe'}, 'level': 100}},

{'user': 'guest', 'record': {'message': 'User Inquiry', 'context': {'session_id': 'YWOZf'}, 'level': 100}}`

while I want a list of dictionaries so that I can call out[0] and so on.

Comment: @JayshworKhadka That's a list of dictionaries without the leading and trailing bracket.