# Change string to list datatype

Tags: python, pandas

How can I change the data type from string to list and also remove the single qoutes outside?

```
x = '["a","b"]'
type(x)
>>> str
```

Desired output is

```
x = ["a","b"]
type(x)
>>> list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you have is valid json, so you can just parse it:

```
import json

x = '["a","b"]'

l = json.loads(x)

print(l)
# ['a', 'b']

print(type(l))
# <class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`eval`](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/):

```
In [933]: eval(x)
Out[933]: ['a', 'b']

In [934]: type(eval(x))
Out[934]: list
```

Comment: Obligatory link to [Security of Python's eval() on untrusted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings)

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to parse the string into a list:

```
import re
x = re.findall(r"\"(\w+)\"", '["a","b"]')
print(x, type(x))
```

Outputs:

```
['a', 'b'] <class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = '["a","b"]'

x[2:-2].split('","')
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain your code. This will make the answer clear to future readers!