# Deserializing array of arrays from a string

Tags: python, arrays, string, deserialization, pickle

I need to deserialize an array of arrays from a string like `'[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]'`.

I tried using pickle, but I didn't really get how to use it.

How can I deserialize this string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval()`:

```py
import ast

ast.literal_eval('[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]')
```

This outputs:

```py
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

(As a side note, you should use `ast.literal_eval()` over `eval()` whenever possible, for security reasons. More information on this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings). `eval()` can be extremely dangerous, and you should only use it unless you're aware of its risks.)

Answer (score 1):

Try library 'json'

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]')
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```