Convert a list of tuples to a list of lists from a dataframe row
I am reading a csv to a dataframe and want to pull out a column from that dataframe and turn it into a list of lists. The data in the column looks like this:
[(123, 456), (789, 101), (321, 654)] 
[(198, 765), (432, 213), (856, 987)]

The column has multiple rows like this
I want to create a list of lists like so:
list_of_lists = [ [123, 456], [789, 101], [321, 654], [198, 765], [432, 213], [856, 987] ]

As requested: The dataframe is created using:
df = pd.read_csv('filename')

The datatype for this row/series is object
I've tried pulling out that column by using tolist():
new_list = df['column_name'].tolist()

but that gives me a list of list of list of tuples like this:
['[(123, 456), (789, 101), (321, 654)]', '[(198, 765), (432, 213), (856, 987)]']

I've tried using list comprehension after tolist():
[list(elem) for elem in new_list] 

and a bunch of other variations of list comprehension but the nested layers make this complex.
An example of the csv file:



column_name




[(123, 456),(789,101),(321,654)]


[(198, 765),(432, 213),(856,987)]




It looks like your dataframe contains a string, not a list of anything. Please make a [mre] that we can run ourselves and see the behaviour. For example, it should at the very least include code to create the dataframe you're using.

The column with the values [(123, 456), (789, 101), (321, 654), (098, 765), (432, 213), (856, 987)]
is a "object" datatype in the dataframe. The dataframe is created using pd.read_csv()

Don't describe things, edit your question to include actual code to initialise the dataframe. I can't run your comment. Please actually read the link [mre]

"Each row has a entry like this:" is a problem. Don't describe the data, include what's necessary to create the data. If you're reading a csv file, include the textual representation of that file. That's what "reproducible" is all about. You need to give us everything necessary to reproduce your situation. Because I'm still convinced you have a dataframe of strings, not a dataframe of lists. But until you supply a complete [mre] it's just a guess. This isn't me being picky, it's fundamentally important to making sure we're helping you with the actual problem

Updated to show the csv format

I don't believe that's correct. The data you provided (when loaded as a csv file) would result in a mangled dataset and not behave as you describe: https://trinket.io/python3/13f726d049  Until you supply a working [mre] (as in, one that behaves the way your question describes), we can't possibly help you, we'd be shooting in the dark (while being spun around, upside down, and drunk).

Don't know what to tell you. That's copy pasted directly from the csv

Try using df['column_name'].apply(lambda v: [[x,y] for x,y in eval(v)])

I have recreated your csv and read it into a pandas dataframe. But I don't know what to do next to get to the list that you show. Please edit your question and show exactly the code you use to get the list_of_tuples.

@OldBoy there is no list of tuples. That is where OP missed. OP has csv and needs to get list of lists from it. You need to help them out. If they had list of tuples they could easily use one of the methods outlined below. But instead they have strings

@Onyambu As per the original question OP stated that df['column_name'].tolist() returned a list of tuples, and even provided the list - it's still in the question. Until we get a clear sample of the code and data there is nothing more we can do to help; which is what my previous comment stated.

@OldBoy look at the results of df['column_name'].tolist(). Its a list of strings and not a list of tuples. Note the presence of the quotation marks. Although OP stated it to be a list of tuples, what they said and what they have is different.

Open the file and take a screenshot. Then write your Minimal example and take a screenahot of that. Then run it and take a screenshot of the result.

@Onyambu You missed the original question which was even less clear.

@OldBoy I did not miss anything. Just click on edited 1 hour ago and you will see all the versions of the question. Notice that even the very first question asked had the list of strings. At no point is the OP getting list of tuples from the dataframe.

@Onyambu df['column_name'].apply(lambda v: [[x,y] for x,y in eval(v)]) has gotten me much closer. That gives me a dataframe with the list of lists I'm looking for. How do I pull that out of the dataframe so its just a python list?

Include .tolist() at the end of the code above

I was actually able to get it to work. @Onyambu's approach worked. Step 1: df = df['column_name'].apply(lambda v: [[x,y] for x,y in eval(v)]) Step 2. aslist = df[0]. Sorry for the confusion

Thank you @Onyambu and everyone else who helped

You should be extremely cautious about using eval() ; https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964364/53341 (the better approach is to load the data correctly, but you still haven't provided screen shots of the real data format) You're probably better off not using csv at all, maybe json or some other structure.

When I tested the [list(elem) for elem in element_list] it worked, I think you just referenced the wrong list.
list_of_tuples = [(123, 456), (789, 101), (321, 654), (98, 765), (432, 213), (856, 987)]
  
list_of_lists = [list(item) for item in list_of_tuples]
print(list_of_lists)

This ended up printing [ [123, 456], [789, 101], [321, 654], [098, 765], [432, 213], [856, 987] ]
For each item in the list, such as (123, 456), can be converted into a list. Instead you need to change each instance of these groups into a list.
I will note that when I was playing around the 0 in front of the 98 did cause an issue. I got SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
Adding on from OldBoy's answer: the number 098 is not valid as Python sees the leading zero as specifying that this is an octal number, but the digits 8 and 9 do not exist in octal numbers.

As commented above, how are you running this against the dataframe row? Are you doing df['column_name].tolist() and then running list comprehension on that? If I do that it does not work

A simple list comprehension does it:
list_of_lists = [[x,y] for (x,y) in list_of_tuples]

as in the following:
list_of_tuples = [(123, 456), (789, 101), (321, 654), (98, 765), (432, 213), (856, 987)]  
list_of_lists = [[x,y] for (x,y) in list_of_tuples]
list_of_lists                                      
[[123, 456], [789, 101], [321, 654], [98, 765], [432, 213], [856, 987]]

Note that the number 098 is not valid as Python sees the leading zero as specifying that this is an octal number, but the digits 8 and 9 do not exist in octal numbers.

Are you doing the list comprehension after running df['column_name'].tolist()? If not, how do I pull out the row without changing the structure to run that list comprehension on it?

When I do that list comprehension I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

I can only work on the data you provided in your original question. If that is not the same as the data you extracted from the pandas dataframe, then you need to add the details.

if you already have the csv file just do pd.read_table("your_csv.csv").column_name.map(lambda v: [[x,y] for x,y in eval(v)])

@Onyambu Don't know what I am doing wrong but this is what I get: df = pd.read_table("pandatest.csv").column_name.map(lambda v: [[x,y] for x,y in eval(v)]) and the result is AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column_name.

@OldBoy First make sure you are able to read the dataset in. Check the columns eg df.columns and see that there is a column called column_name otherwise it wont work. Note that the code I gave did solve OP's issue
